# Vectorizing the labels for Multi-layer perceptron

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to build a MLP model to solve .csv data which has 9 classes and some textual data. These are labels and their counts.

```
7:953,
4:686,
1:568,
2:452,
6:275,
5:242,
3:89,
9:37,
8:19.
```

For MLP, I got to know that we need to vectorize class labels. Is it so?
And when I run following code to do so, I'm facing the following error:

```
y_tr = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_tr, num_classes = 9) # y_tr is numpy array with class labels

y_te = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_te, num_classes = 9) # y_te also a numpy array


**IndexError:** index 9 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 9
```

Help me resolve this.Thank you!!

Sample data:

```
ID  Gene    Variation   Class   Text

1    1      CBL W802*     2    tumorigenesis
2    2      CBL Q249E     2    tumorigenesis
3    3      CBL N454D     3    attractive
4    4      CBL L399V     4    cancer
5    5      CBL V391I     4    cancer
6    6      CBL V430M     5    cancer
7    7      CBL Deletion  1    56
8    8      CBL Y371H     4    cancer
9    9      CBL C384R     4    mutations
10   10     CBL P395A     4    cancer
```

Comment: You have to share a sample or few of the data with the label for somebody to be able to help you resolve this.

Comment: What is in `y_tr` and `y_te`? And please read the section about formatting your code. This way I have to format it for 5 minutes every time you make an edit to even be able to read the question.

Comment: x_tr, x_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(df, labels, test_size = 0.25, stratify = labels)

Comment: y_tr is training part of labels and y_te is the testing split of labels

Comment: Have you tried removing `num_classes` argument?

Comment: Try to do it on this small sample of this 10 rows that you showed here. Is it working there?

Comment: I think while splitting the data into train and test , there is a class missing in y_te . Check whether y_te contains all the 9 classes.